# Save existing QDialog to a *.ui file

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a form generated dynamically from a database table model:

[image]

I there a way to save that form to a *.ui file? I want to allow user to edit that form in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably there must be some limitations on what your users can add and edit?

If so, then maybe you could take a more structured approach and use [QWizard](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html) to provide a simple interface for designing and editing forms. The wizard would generate `ui` files which would then be loaded in your application using the [uic module](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html#module-PyQt4.uic) (if you're using PyQt4, that is - because it does not include the `QUiLoader` class).

Of course, for this to work, you would need to adapt your current procedure for dynamically generating forms so that it also works with `ui` files.

**EDIT**

It looks like [`QAbstractFormBuilder`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractformbuilder.html) provides an API for both loading and saving widgets as ui files. It is part of the QtDesigner module, which is now included in PyQt4.

Having said that, my brief experimentation with the `load()` and `save()` methods did not produce very useful results - but hopefully others will have more luck.

Personally, if I was designing an application like this, I would prefer to generate the ui files myself using a suitable XML library (either Qt's, or one of the several python standard library modules). The structure of a form layout is pretty simple and regular, so the ui files should not be too difficult to replicate. The major benefit of doing things this way is that it allows for complete control over the input and output.

Comment: Yes, i am using PyQt4, > The wizard would generate ui files which would then be loaded in your application using the uic module < Though, how would i generate that ui file?

Comment: Thanks for the link to  QAbstractFormBuilder - will see how i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a load(), but no save() in the QUiLoader:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/quiloader.html#load

The UI file format is documented, and is XML.  So you could write your own .UI file generator:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/designer-ui-file-format.html

In fact, you could attack this problem the other way around.  Instead of generating the dialog using programmatic widget API calls...instead generate a .UI file with XML.  Then you can load it in your app or through QtDesigner.

(Depending on what your app is or is intended to do, you might also look into rethinking it as a QtDesigner plug-in...in which case this functionality might come for free.)

Comment: Thanks for the links. > rethinking it as a QtDesigner plug-in < A plugin can create a desired form in the Designer itself?